# Can I bring my desktop parts with me to Canada?

Tags: airports, tsa

I'm from Philippines and I'll be studying in Canada. I will fly in a week, and I'm suddenly speculating if it's okay to bring my desktop parts as checked-in luggage with me.

I have dismantled my parts from my chasis/case, and I will only be bringing the parts. I have them placed in their original boxes/packaging.

To be precise, the items are the following:

(1) Motherboard - boxed with processor and SSD are still attached on it.

(2) GPU - boxed

(3) Liquid Cooler - boxed (corsair)

(4) Power Supply - boxed (corsair)

(5) RAM - boxed

and

(6) Hard Drive - I will bring with me on my carry-on.

Will I have problems bringing these items with me? I appreciate any response that will help, thank you so much!!

Comment: Is this for your personal computer, and not for resale or anything like that?

Answer (score 4):

(This answer is not as authoritative as I would like, I may delete if someone posts a  better answer.)

My answer refers to customs, not to airline regulations about checked/carry-on baggage (which I also very much doubt would be a problem).

The official Canadian [web page on "bringing goods to Canada"](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/prepare-life-canada/border-entry/bringing-goods.html) says

> When you move to Canada from another country, you may bring your personal and household goods with you without paying duty. You’ll have to pay duty **on any item you bring that hasn’t been used** ...

> If you’re not sure if you have to pay duty on some items, bring sales receipts and registration documents with you.

(emphasis added). They then go on to list categories of items that you wouldn't have to pay duty on *even if they were new* (books, linens, clothes, musical instruments, silverware ...).

If your immigration papers/status are otherwise in order, and it's reasonably plausible that the parts are for a *used* computer that you intend to use for your studies, I would be shocked if border control gave you any trouble at all.

Bringing receipts will (1) support your claim that the computer is used, and (2) in the unlikely event that you're charged duty, establish the value so that you can be charged fairly.

When in doubt, go ahead and declare the items. *Very* worst case (I would be surprised), customs will charge you duty. Likely worst case, you'll have to wait a few minutes longer while someone gets around to telling you everything is fine and you can go ahead.